# Website gives You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: permissions, server, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a hosting at [domain.com](http://domain.com). Everything is fine, but when i access my website [MySite](http://qnrmideast.com/) it gives me `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` All permissions are accordingly. But it give me the this Error. How to solve.

Comment: make sure you have added correct connection string!

Comment: At this time i have added only index.html page. No database yet.

Comment: okay. Also, if you repeatedly try to reload the same website again and again, then your ip address will soon become locked out of the server for a period of 20 minutes or so. so my advice would be to try after some time.

Comment: i have access at different devices. But problem still there.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not have uploaded a suitable index file into your public_html/ directory.

Please have a look below link it will guide you properly.

[cpanel - Upload any/index file.](https://support.krystal.co.uk/entries/23258951-Where-do-I-upload-my-website-files-)

[Cpanel - permission guide](https://support.krystal.co.uk/entries/23136873-What-file-and-directory-permissions-should-I-use-for-my-web-files-)

Comment: I follow the instructions. I have a valid index.html page.

Answer (score 1):

Amir, did you check your web server or website log files? There must be something there that can help you.
I suspect that your problem is related with the options directive in your httpd.conf file.